# Android touch target size below 48dp

Tags: android, google-play, accessibility

I'm getting Android pre-launch report warnings about touch target below 48dp.

I cannot make them any bigger than 35dp wide. It's a table layout. Screen width is used fully and without scrolling cannot make any wider. It's a game.

Are there any options here? Like marking them as special, in game objects that have to be smaller than recommend size. I don't want to be penalized for poor accessibility.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have good accessibility, then touch targets need to be bigger than 48dp, otherwise people who don't have good muscle control won't be able to touch the target.

So you will have to change your design, or make the Game objects not touch targets.